# What is the "properties" scheme in the URL "properties://browser/clickID"?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, url-scheme, facebook-pixel

We're capturing error logs from the web console of people visiting our website. I noticed we started getting this error on the 1st of November 2022:

> XHR error GET properties://browser/clickID

I searched around but I couldn't find anything related to this scheme. Any ideas what the "properties" scheme is?

Looking at the browsers this error appears in, it's exclusively Android and almost 99% Chrome, so I'm thinking maybe it's some new Chrome feature rolled out recently? It doesn't seem to be affecting anything, but I haven't been able to replicate it so I can't tell for sure.

EDIT: Change appears to have been reverted at around 17:00 2nd of November, so I guess it was just a bug introduced by Facebook pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were seeing the same thing and discovered that our Facebook Pixel code snippet was part of the issue. Once we removed that code snippet, those ”XHR error GET properties://browser/clickID” logs have dropped off.

Comment: You might be on to something. This thread on facebook devs claims the same: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/383273690603612/